# Too many open files error when using asyncio/pyppeteer

Tags: python, chromium, python-asyncio, pyppeteer

I'm trying to make requests with headless chrome using pyppeteer. But I  keep getting "OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files" after a certain amount of requests. I checked the open resources of the python process with losf and found out that with every new request there's a new line like the following

```
python3 14840 root   11r  FIFO        0,8      0t0 64208510 pipe
```

Can someone tell me what resources aren't being closed? The code that's producing this error is below

```
def search(self, search_path):
    async def main(url):
        browser = await launch(args=['--no-sandbox'], handleSIGINT=False, handleSIGTERM=False, handleSIGHUP=False)
        page = await browser.newPage()
        await page.setJavaScriptEnabled(False)
        try:
            response = await page.goto(url, options={"timeout": 50000})
        except pyppeteer.errors.TimeoutError:
            pass

        src = await page.content()
        await browser.close()
        return src

    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    url = "https://www.example.com" + search_path
    val = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main(url))
    loop.close()
```

**EDIT**

I managed to close the open pipes by calling

```
browser.process.communicate()
```